# Finding instance of Object type in list

Tags: python, list, search

I have a situation like the code below. I want to find the index of the first instance of the object A. What is the fastest way I can do that?

I know there are a lot of ways to go through the entire list and find it, but is there a way to stop the search once the first one is found?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def print(self):
        print(self.a)

l = [0, 0, A(), 0, A(), 0]
print(l.index(type(A))) # this does not work
```

Comment: Do you want to find the first instance or the index of the first instance?

Comment: index of the first instance, I'll clarify that.

Comment: How can you have a `def print(self)`?

Comment: @SukritKalra, It's Python 3, he can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def __eq__(self,other): #this overrides the equality check
        if isinstance(other,A):
           return self.a==other.a
    def print(self):
        print(self.a)

l = [0, 0, A(), 0, A(), 0]
print(l.index(A()))#now this should work
print A() in l

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
a1 == a2 #True
a1.a = 2
a1 == a2 #False
a2.a = 2
a1 == a2 #True
a2.a = 5
a1 < a2 #Error we would need to overload __cmp__ or __lt__ methods for this to work
```

Comment: what is cmp(I assume a compare from python2) and how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: ahh yeah I should have just done a check for equality ... i didnt really need cmp ...edited

Comment: So does that mean .index is using the given objects __eq__ against everything in the list?

Comment: yes ... at least I believe so ... until it finds a match at which point it returns the index.  I added some more examples of stuff this lets you do ... (note it does not let you do `A() < A()`)

Comment: one more question if you don't mind, what does this __eq__ do that the built in __eq__ doesn't?

Comment: the builtin `__eq__` does not know how to compare custom classes (or more correctly checks if they are the SAME object(same memory)) ... this `__eq__` knows how to compare (for equivelency) your `A` class

Comment: This makes all instances equal to one another, that is generally not a good idea. You are looking for something of the same *type*, and equality usually means something more than that (not all items of the same type are equal, but items that are equal are usually of the same type too).

Comment: no it doesnt it checks their member value for eq...I just had a baby girl on the 6th so excuse the late reply :P

Answer (score 3):

You have to test each object; use a list comprehension and [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get all matching indices:

```
[i for i, ob in enumerate(l) if isinstance(ob, A)]
```

or to get the *first* index, use `next()` and a generator expression:

```
next((i for i, ob in enumerate(l) if isinstance(ob, A)), None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> [i for i, ob in enumerate(l) if isinstance(ob, A)]
[2, 4]
>>> next((i for i, ob in enumerate(l) if isinstance(ob, A)), None)
2
```

Comment: I suppose your answer is a little more detailed than mine was :).  +1 to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way:

```
for index, value in enumerate(l):
    if isinstance(value,A):
        return (index, value)
```